# RubyMine 5.0 requires a new library

Tags: ruby, watir, rubymine

I want to use Watir in my Ruby program, like this

```
require 'watir'
ie = Watir::IE.new
ie.goto 'www.google.com'
```

It works well
but there was no autocompletion when I input  ' ie.' .
What should I do to solve this?

Comment: You will get better support for this in rubymine support forum.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure RubyMine recognizes the external library. If you are using a Bundler-powered project (such as a Rails app), go to `Tools > Bundler > Install`.

Otherwise, add the gem to the project from the project settings.